# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String

Tags: java, string

I'm creating a project that uses `GUI` and one part of it asks for the user to sign in with a username and password.

I keep receiving

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String

error and I'm not sure what to do.

Here is the code:

```
public static String accEnter(String newUsername, String newPassword) {
        try {
            if(newUsername.equals(username) && newPassword.equals(password)) {
                System.out.println(“Welcome” + username);
            }
            else {
                throw new WrongPassWordException();
            }
        }
        catch(WrongPassWordException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The error occurs at

```
 System.out.println(“Welcome” + username);
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Welcome" + username);` you'd better use `"` not `”`

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks

Comment: You can also see the syntax highlighting being messed up. Strings usually have a different color. That is often also a good hint that something is wrong.

Comment: Voting to close for simple typo, unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 2):

The double quotes is the problem. Make it `"` instead of `”` and it should work.